# 10 abelian groups of order n

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

How can I find all natural numbers so that there are (up to isomorphism) exactly 10 abelian groups of order n?

How can I use the main theorem about finite abelian groups to determine those numbers?

Comment: A finite abelian group is isomorphic to the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Find a formula for the number of abelian groups of order $n$ in terms of the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: Start by finding out how many abelian group there are of order $p^a$ for prime $p$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson isn't that the number of partitions? For n =1 it's 1, for n=2 it's  2, for n=3 it's 3, for n=4 it's 5... And so on?

Comment: Yes. So now you need to know ow many abelian groups there are of order $mn$ if you know the numbers of orders $m$ and $n$, with $\gcd(m,n)=1$. You may also want to look at http://oeis.org/A000688 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995947/all-isomorphic-classes-of-abelian-groups-of-order-n

Comment: Yes, that is by the main theorem for a given order for example 20=5*2^2 the product of partitions of the powers so p(1)*p(2)=2

Comment: So far I have just tried for a few n.. But I can't find any regularity to make some kind of Formular

Comment: There are only so many ways to multiply together vaues of the partition function to get 10.

Comment: @GerryMyerson okay yes I guess that's my only way for me then ^^ thank you

Comment: So when you have it figured out, let me encourage you to write it up and post an answer.

Comment: So, any progress, then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.